# Pylons root route ('') not behaving as ('/')

Tags: django, routes, pylons

I'm brand spanking new to Pylons, but I'm novice level with Django and expert level with Rails and CakePHP.

This **works**:

```
map.connect('/', controller='hello', action='index')
```

This **doesn't work**:

```
map.connect('', controller='hello', action='index')
```

Results in:

> Not Found
>   The resource could not be found.
>   WSGI Server

The `''` syntax is verbatum from [the Pylons "Getting Started" guide](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonsdocs/Getting+Started#interactive-debugger) and is identical to Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/urls-routing-and-dispatch.html.

from my experience you cant set route to be an empty string ("")